# Python Requests Does Not get website that opens on browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been trying to access this website `https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/tents-accessories`  with requests module but it just keeps processing and does not stop while the same website works fine on browser. Scrappy gives a time out error for the same website. Is there something that should be taken into account while accessing websites like these. Thanks

Comment: I can't even access the website using browser, did you try using `requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)`?

Comment: In your case it may be the location problem. It works in US only I think.

Answer (score 6):

For sites like these you can try to add the extra headers that your browser does. Following these steps worked for me -

1. Open the link in incognito window with the network tab open.
2. Copy the first request made by right clicking -> copy -> copy as curl
3. Go to https://curl.trillworks.com/. Paste the curl command to get the equivalent python requests code.
4. Now try removing headers one by one until it works with the minimal headers.

Image for reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRS98.png

Edit -

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.dickssportinggoods.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/tents-accessories', headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Hey can u also show the code that worked for you?

Comment: Hey, So i am using vpn becuase this site is only accessible within the states. I think that causes the problem. Although i am using premium vpn and i have used nord, express, surfshark etc none of which seem to work. So do u have any idea what would be the problem here?

Comment: the curl converter link was not working for me so I used this [one](https://curlconverter.com/python/)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding headers?

```py
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/tents-accessories', headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score -1):

So Thanks to @Marcel and @Sonal but appart from headers, it just worked when i put the statement in a try/except block.

```
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0\
                             Win64\
                             x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36'
    }
    session = requests.Session()

    try:
        r = session.get(
            link, headers=headers, stream=True)

        return r
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        r.status_code = "Connection refused"
```